# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed" in python, while using a simple custom web browser

Tags: python, sockets, browser

This is the syntax of the web browser I'm building:

```
"import socket
mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Please Enter the website url and port below, else the default port will be used')
print('\rWebsite:')
website=input()
print('\rPORT:')
port=input()
if len(website)<2:
    print("/n You have entered an Invalid Link")
if len(port)<1:
    port=80
while len(website)>1:
    mysock.connect((website, (int(port))))
    cmd=('GET'+website+'HTTP/1.0 \r\n\r\n').encode()
    mysock.send(cmd)
    while True:
        data=mysock.recv(512)
        if len(data) < 1:
            break
        print(data.decode(),end='')
    mysock.close()
"
```

I'm trying to access this link:
http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt through port 80 but receive

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PLAY\Documents\python work\browser.py", line 13, in <module>
    mysock.connect((website, (int(port))))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed"
```

What's going on here and how could I improve it? I'm just messing around with the code abit and would like to understand more and make it more functional so I can build on top of it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `socket.connect()` expects an IP address or host name, not an URL. Use only "data.pr4e.org" for `website`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a whole URL to `socket.connect()`, only an IP/hostname and a port number.  So, you would need to parse the user's input and break it up into its constituent components, and then you can act on them.

If the user enters `http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt`, you need to break that up into `http`, `data.pr4e.org`, and `/romeo.txt`.  Connect the socket to `data.pr4e.org` on port 80 (because `http` is used), and then send a request for `GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` (note the spaces!).

Python has a [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module for parsing URLs.

A better option is to use the [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) module, or even the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, instead of a socket manually.  Let the module/library do all of the URL parsing and socket handling for you.  You give them a URL to access, they give you back the downloaded data from that location.

Comment: The reason I chose to use the sockets library was because I was attempting to master it before moving on to the urllib but you have answered my question in a way that both works in practice and makes me understand the concept, thanks.